# ListView doesn't show android sqlite items

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a problem with showing data items from sqlite database with ListView.
When i try to see the data after click button, it shows:

> com.LocationReminder and Task@4053afb0

It's weird.

This is my readReminder.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class readReminder extends ListActivity {
private DBReminder operasiDB;
private ArrayList<Task> daftarTugas;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.read_task);
     operasiDB = new DBReminder(this);

     daftarTugas = operasiDB.viewAllTask();
     ArrayAdapter<Task> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Task>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, daftarTugas);

     setListAdapter(adapter);
 }
}
```

this is my code to show all data from database

```
public ArrayList<Task> viewAllTask() {
    openConn();
    ArrayList<Task> tugas = new ArrayList<Task>();
    Cursor curs = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TableName, null);
    if (curs.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Task task = new Task();
            task.setId(Integer.parseInt(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(ID))));
    task.setLatitude(Integer.parseInt(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(LATITUDE))));               
task.setLongitude(Integer.parseInt(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(LONGITUDE)));
task.setRadius(Integer.parseInt(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(RADIUS))));
task.setAlamat(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(ALAMAT)));
task.setKonteks(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(KONTEKS_TUGAS)));
tugas.add(task);
        } while (curs.moveToNext());
    }
    closeConn();
    return tugas;
}
```

In the SQLite Manager Eclipse, the data is appear also with the table.
Please help me. Thank you...

Comment: I think sqlite database will return the data as cursor objects.so try with cursoradapter instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own `Adapter` by extending the `ArrayAdapter` class.

Comment: How i can make it?? should i make another class just for Adapter?

Comment: Yeah you should create another class and override its 'getView' method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show multiple columns in your listview use SimpleCursorAdapter

```
public Cursor viewAllTask() {
//openConn(); open your database in the activity onCreate

return db.rawQuery("select * from " + TableName, null);

//closeConn(); // close your database in the activity onDestroy
}
```

Change `private ArrayList<Task> daftarTugas;` 
To `Cursor daftarTugas;`

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.read_task);
 operasiDB = new DBReminder(this);
 operasiDB.open();

 Cursor daftarTugas = operasiDB.viewAllTask();
 String[] fromColumns = {DBReminder.RADIUS, 
                         DBReminder.ALAMAT,
                         DBReminder.KEY_KONTEKS_TUGAS};
int[] toViews = {R.id.textview_radius, 
                 R.id.textview_alamat,
                 R.id.textview_konteks_tugas};
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                            R.layout.listview_items,
                            daftarTugas, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

Layout XML name listview_items

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_radius"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textview_alamat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textview_konteks_tugas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i want to show 3 columns of data. Radius, alamat or the address, and konteks tugas or task context. thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default ArrayAdaptor class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView.you need to custom it.

simple and easy way to use simplecursoradoptor.